# Laravel abruptly truncating my database table

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am using version control for my project. After some updates and commit when I run my project again, I have observed that laravel is truncating my Category table.

There are two ways to seed table.

- `DatabaseSeeder` and with `php artisan db:seed` and
- Specific table    seeder class by using 
  `php artisan db:seed --class="CategoriesTableSeeder"`

I am not able to catch behavior when its truncating my table.
I have tested it by commenting all line in the `public function run(){}` inside `DatabaseSeeder` class and also by commenting `DB::table('categories')->insert($categories);` and `DB::table('categories')->truncate();` in `CategoriesTableSeeder` class.

Because table is getting truncated automatically, I have to seed it again and again.

Any idea???

Comment: Is it a possibility that Category table has some foreign key with ON DELETE CASCADE settings? that way you might be truncating some other table and category table is being truncated automatically.

Comment: Did you copy and paste any of the seeder code to a different seeder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem have gone through all the possibilities. Searched through out the migration files and seed files everything was file. Its already more than 10 days, I was unable to resolve. Gone through the users comments also. But all that did not worked.

One day, I was checking database architecture and I found that engine for categories table was "Memory".

By default I had my database engine set to "InnoDB".

Changed it to "InnoDB" and Problem gone.